# Hadoop giving error "ls: Failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException: RPC response exceeds maximum data length"

Tags: 14.04, hadoop

Folks,
I've literally searched everywhere, spent ounces and ounces of time. Can you please help me here? I have Java 8 and Hadoop 2.9.1 in my Ubuntu 14.04. After I type `start-all.sh`, services do get started. In fact, when I type `jps`, I get the following:-

```
knjayanth@knjayanth-Inspiron-3558:~/Jayanth/Hadoop/sbin$ jps
25985 Jps
25378 SecondaryNameNode
25574 ResourceManager
25160 DataNode
```

However, `hdfs dfs -ls` command returns an error like below:-

```
knjayanth@knjayanth-Inspiron-3558:~/Jayanth/Hadoop/sbin$ hdfs dfs -ls
ls: Failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException: RPC response exceeds maximum data length; Host Details : local host is: "knjayanth-Inspiron-3558/127.0.1.1"; destination host is: "localhost":9000;
```

Can someone be kind enough to assist me? I've searched extensively for help, but not getting it. Kindly assist.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49060244/exception-org-apache-hadoop-ipc-rpcexception-rpc-response-exceeds-maximum-da

Comment: @Thomas thanks, but that doesn't solve either. Can you assist?

Comment: Might be a problem with the port number you are using. Try this : <https://stackoverflow.com/a/60701948/8504709>

Answer (score 1):

Check your host settings in **core-site.xml**. I think you’ve configured it as *localhost:9000* but your hostname is *knjayanth-Inspiron-3558/127.0.1.1* . Change your **fs.defaultFS** value in **core-site.xml** to ***knjayanth-Inspiron-3558/127.0.1.1*** and restart your namenode.

Comment: Hi, still doesnt work. Getting the following error:
knjayanth@knjayanth-Inspiron-3558:~/hadoop$ hdfs dfs -ls
18/11/28 21:35:59 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
ls: Call From knjayanth-Inspiron-3558/127.0.1.1 to knjayanth-Inspiron-3558:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
knjayanth@knjayanth-Inspiron-3558:~/hadoop$

Comment: Connection refused error means the namenode server is not running. Run *start-dfs.sh* or *start-all.sh* to start namenode server. You can check the status of the namenode server by running the *jps* command. If it's running then you should be able to see it in the jps results. You can also check the namenode logs at /var/log/hadoop/hdfs/ for more information about errors etc.

Answer (score 0):

The *connection refused* error could be because your namenode server is not running. You can check the status of namenode server by running the **jps** command. 
If it's running, you should be able to see **Namenode** service in the results of jps. If it's not, then you may want to try the following:

1. Stop all running services by executing **stop-all.sh** script
2. Format the namenode server by running **hadoop namenode -format** (Note that this command removes all of your stored data in hdfs). This step is not that necessary, so you can skip it
3. Restart namenode by executing **start-dfs.sh** or **start-all.sh** to start all the services including the YARN services
4. Run **jps** to check if namenode is running

You can also check the hdfs namenode logs in */var/log/hadoop/hdfs* to get more information on where the issue could be.

Hope this helps.

Best of luck :)